# buildroot for arm kernel defconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, arm, cross-compiling, buildroot

I am trying to build a buildroot with kernel image, and after doing `make menuconfig` and `make`, I am getting:

```
No kernel defconfig name specified, check your BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG setting
```

I can set a string to the `defconfig`, but I don't know what to put there.

My target system is an AT91SAM9RL board.

**edit**: I found out there are some pre-made config files to some devices, actually not exactly matching to my target.

Comment: Here I describe a sample minimal runnable setup for QEMU: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557262/how-to-download-the-torvalds-linux-kernel-master-recompile-it-and-boot-it-wi/49349237#49349237

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can issue the default configuration process by running `make xxx_defconfig` and that make target is a file in the folder `arch/arm/configs/`. These default configurations are not designed to exactly fit your target, but are rather meant to be a superset so you only have to modify them a bit.

The `make xxx_defconfig` creates your initial `.config`, which you can now edit through `make menuconfig` and make your changes. After that, you can run `make` which will then compile the kernel using your settings.

Comment: Ok i got it, seems like its working. Pretty long buildtime in a VM tough.

Comment: I would just add that defconfig files are now in buildroot root directory configs subfolder (buildroot-2012.02).

Comment: Not exactly. `configs` subfolder contains buildroot defconfig which points to a linux defconfig located in `board` subfolder. e.g. `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="board/freescale/mpc8315erdb/linux-3.12.config"`

Comment: Why must the configuration file's name end with 'defconfig'?

Comment: When you clone git repository of buildroot you can find some default configuration files in the config directory. all this files are called <something>_defconfig (like raspberrypi_defconfig)