# Kernel defconfig in buildroot (arm target)

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, cross-compiling, buildroot

Debian 8 x64, buildroot 2016.02 / 2016-05-07 / 2016-05-13.
After `make menuconfig` and set some settings I run `make`. There is an error appears:

> linux/linux.mk:424: *** No kernel defconfig name specified, check your
>   BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG setting.  Stop.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332879/buildroot-for-arm-kernel-defconfig) does not help: my `arch/arm/configs/` folder does not exist in *every* release/snapshot I've tried. There is only `arch` folder with this content:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  11K May 12 19:21 Config.in
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  176 May 12 19:21 Config.in.aarch64
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 1.7K May 12 19:21 Config.in.arc
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  15K May 12 19:21 Config.in.arm
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 2.2K May 12 19:21 Config.in.bfin
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  735 May 12 19:21 Config.in.m68k
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  279 May 12 19:21 Config.in.microblaze
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 2.1K May 12 19:21 Config.in.mips
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   70 May 12 19:21 Config.in.nios2
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 5.5K May 12 19:21 Config.in.powerpc
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  693 May 12 19:21 Config.in.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  617 May 12 19:21 Config.in.sparc
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 7.5K May 12 19:21 Config.in.x86
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 1.5K May 12 19:21 Config.in.xtensa
```

I've tried to create `arch/arm/configs/` folder and put there `arch/Config.in.arm` file (renamed to `arm_defconfig`/whatever) or empty file (renamed).
Whatever `Kernel - Defconfig name` I set, it does not helps.
`make BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG` also does not helps. Option is not documented in Buildroot user manual.
`make linux-menuconfig` returns same error if no `Kernel - Defconfig name` seted or

> Can't find default configuration "arch/arm/configs/name_defconfig"!

where `name` is `Kernel - Defconfig name` variable. I've tried to set this to `arm`, `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG` and many other names.

Can you help me, how to set default kernel configuration from buildroot developers?

Comment: What happens, when you invoke for example `make beaglebone_defconfig && make clean && make`?

Comment: What is your *"arm target"*?  What is (esp. the last half) *"Debian 8 x64, buildroot 2016.02 / 2016-05-07 / 2016-05-13."*?

Comment: Answer by Arnout was right, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kernel defconfig is a configuration file in the *kernel* tree, not the buildroot tree. You have to look in [`arch/arm/configs` in the kernel](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/configs). Find the defconfig there that is appropriate for your target CPU. If you are not using an upstream kernel, you'll have to check with the vendor which defconfig to use. Remember to remove the `_defconfig` part of the name.

If you really have no idea at all, `multi_v5` and `multi_v7` are safe options: they include support for all possible processors with an ARMv5 resp. ARMv7 architecture.

You will probably encounter the same issue with the device tree. You can find the device trees (the `.dts` files) in [`arch/arm/boot/dts` in the kernel tree](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts). This one does have to match exactly with your board.